# Record audio in OS X into FLAC using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio

I am trying to record audio from a microphone/iSight camera from Mac to a `NSData` object.
I have tried to do it using QTKit, but I found out that you could only save it as a `.mov` file.

But the fact is that I want to recode the audio into a FLAC file. Is that posible, or I'll need to use another framework?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the source for VLC (if you can deal w/GPL -- it has limitations on use that many find onerous) and have a read.   It does transcoding, amongst other things.

Beyond that, one dead simple approach is to save as AIFF and then use a command line tool (via NSTask) to do the conversion.

Or you could just go with Apple Lossless -- it is open source these days.

Of course, this also begs the question;  why do you need lossless compression when recording voice [low bandwidth in the first place] via a relatively sub-par microphone?